# extracting subset of data points from several cross sections

Tags: r

I want to take only those wells among the data file which have continuous data points (every year from 1997 to 2017). My data looks like this. all these wells don't have continuous data from 1997 to 2017. I want to extract only those wellss havinf level data for each year from 1997 to 2017.

```
well.   year.   level
W04790  2018    14.99
W04824  2018    8.05
W04791  2018    10.85
W04299  2018    8.87
W04797  2018    4.3
W04039  2018    7.25
W04799  2018    5.58
W04300  2018    14.35
W04790  2017    14.99
W04824  2017    7.9
W04791  2017    9.6
W04295  2017    8.24
W04299  2017    8.87
W04797  2017    4.4
W04039  2017    7.3
W04799  2017    5.65
W25596  2017    2.83
W04302  2017    2.6
W04300  2017    0.63
W32596  2016    5.69
W32607  2016    2.15
W32602  2016    10.9
W32605  2016    12.47
W32612  2016    10.65
W32635  2016    3.78
W32490  2016    9.95
W32491  2016    4.03
W32485  2016    5.6
W32505  2016    3.13
W31146  2016    3.9
W32537  2016    7.46
W32530  2016    2.41
W32540  2016    6.35
W32545  2016    5
W32549  2016    5.3
W32547  2016    5.26
W32554  2016    6.79
W32557  2016    7.97
W32572  2016    8.2
W32575  2016    9.03
W32577  2016    9.8
W32510  2016    5.01
W32503  2016    2.9
W32501  2016    1.35
W32509  2016    15.54
W04822  2016    11.75
W04807  2016    7.95
W04287  2016    8.03
W04819  2016    5.46
W04040  2016    2.3
W04298  2016    8.62
W04303  2016    12.12
W04297  2016    9.54
W04299  2016    8.87
W04797  2016    4.34
W04799  2016    5.6
W25598  2016    7.36
W25612  2016    8.8
W04809  2015    4.86
W04826  2015    3.73
W04792  2015    13.15
W04798  2015    9.54
W04034  2015    14.51
W04793  2015    9.25
W03834  2015    4.62
W04808  2015    12.42
W04043  2015    7.68
W04795  2015    12.34
W04037  2015    12.22
W04822  2015    10.72
W04821  2015    6.53
W04807  2015    7.95
W04295  2015    8.24
W04299  2015    8.87
W04797  2015    3.69
W25404  2014    3.93
W25438  2014    7.18
W25451  2014    5.56
W25476  2014    4.37
W25293  2014    5.06
W04809  2014    4.07
W04792  2014    10.45
W04798  2014    9.35
W04034  2014    14.51
W04809  2013    4.3
W25293  2013    5.1
W04798  2013    8.75
W04034  2013    11.55
W03834  2013    5.14
W04808  2013    10.72
W04043  2013    6.8
W04795  2013    11.82
W04822  2013    11.7
W04821  2013    4.5
W04807  2013    3.65
W04806  2013    5.4
W04287  2013    8.4
W04288  2013    5.2
W03836  2013    4.33
W04811  2013    5.46
W03835  2013    4.9
W04293  2013    2.8
W04819  2013    4.26
W04042  2013    12.7
W04798  2012    11.5
W04034  2012    11.45
W03834  2012    5.59
W04808  2012    12.32
W04043  2012    9
W04795  2012    12.67
W04822  2012    11.8
W04821  2012    8.3
W04807  2012    4.35
W04806  2012    7.9
W04287  2012    9
W04288  2012    5.75
W03836  2012    4.13
W03835  2012    6.6
W04809  2011    4.04
W04799  2011    4.52
W04798  2011    9.28
W04034  2011    11.08
W03834  2011    5.63
W04808  2011    11.27
W04043  2011    7.8
W04795  2011    12.37
W04822  2011    10.7
W04821  2011    7.26
W04807  2011    3.04
W04806  2011    5.51
W04287  2011    7.82
W04288  2011    4.15
W03836  2011    3.38
W04811  2011    5.16
W03835  2011    8.49
W04293  2011    1.95
W04819  2011    4.04
W04042  2011    9.65
W04789  2011    6.35
W03833  2011    3.01
W04040  2011    1.73
W04283  2011    16.44
W04801  2011    4.4
W04298  2011    7.51
W04302  2011    2.89
W04300  2011    1.21
W04809  2010    4.6
W04792  2010    12.38
W04798  2010    10.3
W04034  2010    11.37
W03834  2010    4.54
W04808  2010    10.02
W04043  2010    10.32
W04795  2010    12.56
W04822  2010    11.57
W04821  2010    4.27
W04807  2010    5.47
W04806  2010    8.44
W04287  2010    8.14
W04288  2010    5.57
W03836  2010    2.81
W04811  2010    5.36
W03835  2010    10.01
W04293  2010    4.48
W04819  2010    4.29
W04042  2010    17.87
W04789  2010    7.94
W03833  2010    3.73
W04797  2009    3.6
W03834  2009    4.29
W04799  2009    4.8
W04281  2009    6.6
W04790  2009    10.05
W04824  2009    4.88
W04791  2009    8.52
W04295  2009    7.04
W04299  2009    6.57
W04300  2009    1.85
W04296  2009    5.66
W04816  2009    4.06
W04303  2009    11.97
W04797  2008    3.15
W04790  2008    7.77
W04824  2008    5.96
W04791  2008    7.92
W04295  2008    6.84
W04299  2008    6.94
W04300  2008    2.5
W04296  2008    5.6
W04816  2008    3.81
W04303  2008    13.5
W03914  2008    9.9
W04281  2008    5.9
W03833  2008    3.46
W04040  2008    2.18
W04283  2008    16.83
W04801  2008    1.55
W04298  2008    4.36
W04302  2008    1.93
W03835  2008    8.75
W04293  2008    3.44
W04819  2008    3.51
W04042  2008    11.88
W04789  2008    7.14
W04806  2008    7.2
W04287  2008    7.82
W04288  2008    4.64
W03836  2008    3.31
W04039  2008    7.12
W04797  2007    4.55
W03834  2007    4.21
W04799  2007    7.35
W04790  2007    12.65
W04824  2007    5.95
W04791  2007    8.9
W04295  2007    6.96
W04299  2007    7.64
W04300  2007    2.55
W04296  2007    6.7
W04816  2007    5
W04303  2007    8
W03914  2007    9.18
W04281  2007    8.25
W04286  2007    7.32
W04040  2007    2.53
W04283  2007    16.8
W04801  2007    2.1
W04298  2007    7.76
W04302  2007    3.3
W03835  2007    9.45
W04293  2007    3.95
W04819  2007    4.91
W04042  2007    13
W04789  2007    8.35
W03833  2007    5.21
W04299  2006    6.24
W04300  2006    3.25
W04296  2006    4.65
W04816  2006    6.33
W04818  2006    3.4
W04303  2006    13.31
W03914  2006    8.15
W04281  2006    6.45
W04286  2006    5.7
W04040  2006    1.78
W04283  2006    16.45
W04801  2006    2.55
W04298  2006    6.51
W04302  2006    2.25
W03835  2006    8.4
W04293  2006    2.65
W04819  2006    5.24
W04042  2006    9.66
W04290  2006    9.58
W04789  2006    6.3
W04806  2006    7
W04287  2006    7.4
W04288  2006    4.35
W03836  2006    3.3
W04811  2006    4.68
W04043  2006    7.5
W04795  2006    11.92
W04037  2006    11.63
W04822  2006    9.6
W04821  2006    3.8
W04807  2006    4.33
W04821  2005    4.06
W04807  2005    8.35
W04809  2005    5.27
W04820  2005    5.95
W04792  2005    9.85
W04798  2005    9.75
W04034  2005    10.05
W03834  2005    3.34
W04038  2005    8.71
W04796  2004    7.5
W04808  2004    9.52
W04799  2004    5.2
W04790  2004    9.9
W04823  2004    5.28
W04824  2004    4.4
W04791  2004    8.84
W04295  2004    6.89
W04299  2004    8.87
W04797  2004    3.53
W04301  2004    9.9
W04296  2004    8.7
W04816  2004    4.95
W04818  2004    12.5
W04303  2004    15.47
W03914  2004    9.58
W04281  2004    6.52
W04286  2004    5.95
W04040  2004    3.33
W04283  2004    17.1
W04801  2004    6.28
W04298  2004    7.19
W04302  2004    3.66
W04300  2004    5.75
W04293  2004    7.58
W04042  2004    14.77
W04035  2004    8.68
W04290  2004    9.84
W04789  2004    8.8
W03833  2004    4.69
W04806  2004    9.45
W04287  2004    8.7
W04288  2004    5.13
W03836  2004    4.93
W04815  2004    10.75
W04811  2004    7.96
W04810  2004    8.52
W04037  2003    24.9
W04822  2003    12.37
W04821  2003    3.47
W04807  2003    8.51
W04809  2003    6.84
W04820  2003    8.32
W04036  2003    6.67
W04792  2003    16.35
W04034  2003    10.25
W04038  2003    8.38
W04796  2002    8.3
W04793  2002    10.3
W04039  2002    8.4
W04799  2002    5.5
W04790  2002    10.36
W04823  2002    4.42
W04824  2002    8.51
W04791  2002    8.3
W04295  2002    6.89
W04299  2002    8.87
W04797  2002    3.4
W04301  2002    9.9
W04816  2002    7.47
W04818  2002    10.32
W04303  2002    15.25
W03914  2002    10.48
W04789  2002    8.72
W03833  2002    6.05
W04806  2002    9.93
W04287  2002    11.35
W04288  2002    5.65
W04815  2002    4.25
W04811  2002    5.54
W04810  2002    10.51
W04038  2002    7.21
W04796  2001    5.9
W04793  2001    9.6
W04039  2001    7.5
W04799  2001    4.7
W04790  2001    11.2
W04823  2001    8.06
W04791  2001    7.7
W04295  2001    7.07
W04299  2001    8.87
W04797  2001    1.65
W04301  2001    9.9
W04818  2001    5.35
W03914  2001    9.28
W04281  2001    7.1
W04286  2001    6.66
W04040  2001    2.63
W04283  2001    12.7
W04298  2001    7.41
W04302  2001    4.18
W04300  2001    2.85
W04819  2001    5.09
W04805  2001    9.7
W04042  2001    8.25
W04035  2001    9.98
W04290  2001    9.84
W04789  2001    7.15
W04806  2001    8.58
W04287  2001    9.45
W04288  2001    5.62
W04815  2001    2.55
W04811  2001    5.84
W04810  2001    9.96
W03835  2001    9.4
W04043  2001    9.9
W04795  2001    9.62
W04037  2001    15.88
W04822  2001    12.2
W04821  2001    3.13
W04807  2001    6.48
W04809  2001    6.2
W04820  2001    4.08
W04036  2001    6.59
W04792  2001    7.42
W04034  2001    10.28
W04038  2001    6.81
W04796  2000    7.25
W04793  2000    9.52
W04039  2000    6.03
W04799  2000    4.66
W04041  2000    2.77
W04790  2000    7.77
W04823  2000    6.26
W04791  2000    7.9
W04295  2000    6.24
W04299  2000    8.36
W04797  2000    1.58
W04816  2000    4.28
W04818  2000    7.75
W04303  2000    14.95
W03914  2000    8.72
W04281  2000    7.88
W04040  2000    5.78
W04283  2000    15.72
W04298  2000    6.74
W04302  2000    4.61
W04300  2000    8.65
W04819  2000    3.98
W04805  2000    8.02
W03914  1999    10.81
W04281  1999    8.6
W04790  1999    13.19
W04823  1999    4.22
W04791  1999    8.19
W04295  1999    7.33
W04299  1999    8.88
W04797  1999    4.2
W04796  1999    8.3
W04038  1999    7.42
W04039  1999    7.8
W04799  1999    5.49
W04811  1999    6.08
W04810  1999    7.63
W03835  1999    8.87
W04819  1999    4.63
W04805  1999    8.39
W04035  1999    7.36
W04789  1999    6.91
W03833  1999    6.91
W04040  1999    2.85
W04298  1999    5.17
W04302  1999    3.58
W04300  1999    4.72
W04818  1999    11.43
W04036  1999    6.32
W04792  1999    16.98
W04034  1999    11.09
W04793  1999    10.95
W04043  1999    8.7
W04795  1999    12.91
W04822  1999    11.53
W04821  1999    3.63
W04807  1999    6.3
W04806  1999    8.88
W04288  1999    5.7
W04815  1999    2.45
W03914  1998    11.55
W04815  1998    5.01
W04281  1998    6.95
W04790  1998    13.28
W04823  1998    3.54
W04791  1998    7.66
W04295  1998    5.99
W04299  1998    3.13
W04797  1998    2.59
W04796  1998    6.08
W04038  1998    7.68
W04039  1998    6.95
W04799  1998    5.32
W04811  1998    4.52
W04810  1998    7.4
W04819  1998    3.81
W04805  1998    7.9
W04035  1998    9.07
W04789  1998    9.01
W03833  1998    5.72
W04799  1997    5.54
W04041  1997    4.57
W04811  1997    5.08
W04810  1997    6.16
W03835  1997    7.56
W04819  1997    4.85
W04805  1997    7.9
W04035  1997    7.77
W04789  1997    8.27
W03833  1997    6.27
W04040  1997    4.65
W04298  1997    6.18
W04302  1997    4
W04300  1997    8.37
W04301  1997    7.04
W04818  1997    11.92
W04820  1997    5.64
W04036  1997    5.79
W04792  1997    12.94
W04034  1997    10.77
W04793  1997    10.14
W04043  1997    9.22
W04795  1997    13.3
W04822  1997    11.98
W04821  1997    7.86
W04807  1997    5.6
W03832  1997    10.26
W04806  1997    8.57
W04288  1997    5.42
W04297  1997    6.91
W03914  1996    11.12
W04815  1996    6.42
W04281  1996    8.07
W04790  1996    9.97
W04823  1996    4.83
W04791  1996    7.62
W04295  1996    6.93
W04299  1996    7.89
W04797  1996    2.86
W04796  1996    7.42
W04038  1996    6.74
W04039  1996    7.05
W04799  1996    5.04
W04041  1996    8.77
W04811  1996    4.94
W04810  1996    6.6
W03835  1996    9.48
W04819  1996    5.13
W04805  1996    8.17
W04035  1996    9.21
W04789  1996    5.33
W03833  1996    6.11
W04040  1996    6.93
W04298  1996    6.64
W04302  1996    4.81
W04300  1996    7.15
W04301  1996    7.8
W04818  1996    11.62
W04820  1996    5.77
W04036  1996    6.59
W04792  1996    11.1
W04034  1996    10
W04793  1996    9.6
W04043  1996    7.44
W04795  1996    12.81
W04822  1996    11.81
W04821  1996    9.66
W04807  1996    5.55
W04788  1996    5.49
W03832  1996    10.94
W04806  1996    8.4
```

How I can do that, Please help

Comment: `subset(df,date>=1996 & date<=2017)`?

Comment: Error in date >= 1996 : 
  comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: What have you tried? Do you only want to keep wells which have data points from 1996 to 2017 (i.e. 20 data points)?

Comment: What do you mean by `continuous data points`?

Comment: @priyankaupreti That code works for data frames, what kind of data do you have and in which format? It is better to paste your data by using the `dput()` function on it.

Comment: yes sir. only those wells having continuous data from 1996 to 2017

Comment: continuous means every single year from 1996 to 2017.

Comment: Since 2003 and 2004 are missing for all wells, none of the them have continuous data from 1996 to 2017.

Comment: In this context the term continuous is used to mean from, think I @Aron

Comment: oh sorry, I have just updated the data for 2003 and 2004 as well

Comment: The data you uploaded starts from 1996 now? So just go with `subset(df, date <=2017)`? Otherwise, the snippet from the first comment should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that between 1996 and 2017, there are 22 years (both years including). So you count them:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% add_count(well) %>%
  filter(n == 22)
```

(Assuming your data.frame is named `df` and the well-column is actually named `well` and not `well.`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir for your help. It really helped. :-)